# failed to upload file in s3 bucket react-aws-s3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file from my react app to my s3 bucket but unfortunately, I'm unable to achieve it, I might be doing something wrong with my permissions of account and s3 bucket, even though my user and user group have AdministratorAccess. My bucket is public as well. I have attached my react code with s3 bucket policies as well.

```
const config = {
    bucketName: BUCKET_NAME,
    dirName: BUCKET_DIR,
    region: BUCKET_REGION,
    accessKeyId: BUCKET_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: BUCKET_SECRET_KEY,
};

const ReactS3Client = new S3(config);

ReactS3Client.uploadFile(file, 'test')
            .then((data) => console.log('Data:', data))
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('err => ', err);
            });
```

s3 bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PolicyForAllowUploadWithACL",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {}
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow anyone to get objects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

CORS enabled:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "HEAD",
            "GET",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Comment: What is the error you're seeing?  It's possibly a permissions issue.  Does the S3 bucket have versioning enabled?  You might need the GetObjectVersion permission.  Perhaps also eliminate whether it's an application related error by performing the upload using the same credentials with the AWS CLI.

Comment: no bucket versioning is not enabled, the the error is `failed to fetch`

Comment: I have attached the policy you can see the permissions there.

Comment: Not that this makes a whole lot of sense since you've got both the bucketName and direName defined in your config, but try adding the s3Url as per `https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com` (https://github.com/Fausto95/aws-s3/issues/78#issuecomment-837417434)

Comment: @Norman After adding bucket name do I need to do any additional things?

Comment: @ZainKhan, did you solve the issue? I am facing same issue,

Comment: @JaynaTanawala yes using AWS-SDK.